# Próximo elemento do loop

Tags: git, for, bash

Estou tentando implementar um algoritmo de busca de commits entre duas tags com o comando `git log tag1...tag2`. Para isso utilizei o comando `git tag` que me retorna as tags de um repositório.

Com esse resultado, pensei em iterar sobre ele executando o comando `git`

```
for tag in $Tags
do
    git log $tag .. $proximaTag
done
```

Minha dúvida é: Como conseguir o valor da próxima tag? Nesse caso, como conseguir o valor do próximo item no array?

Tem alguma forma melhor de implementar esse tipo de algoritmo?

Comment: não conheço muito de bash, mas seguindo a lógica de programção, não teria como você pegar o index dessa iteração? ai você faria algo como $tags[i] .. $tags[++i]. Porém, provavelmente você teria que fazer um index auxiliar para não modificar o valor do atual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso do laço `for` você não terá como pegar o próximo elemento da lista mas é possível usar o laço `while` e o comando `shift` para fazê-lo:

```
show_commits(){    
    first_tag=${1}
    while true; do
        shift
        next_tag=${1}
        if [[ $next_tag == '' ]]; then
            break
        else
            git log "${first_tag}".."${next_tag}" --pretty=%H
            echo
            first_tag=$next_tag
        fi
    done
}

show_commits $( git tag | tac )
```

A lista de *tags* é gerada diretamente pelo Git e o comando `tac` serve para inverter a ordem dela) e toda ela é enviada para a função como os argumentos $1, $2, $3 etc. Mas você pode fazer algo direto como "show_commits v1.2.3 v1.2.2 v1.0.0".

Porém, apesar de receber todos eles, a função usará apenas um argumento, veja que somente um argumento -- `${1}` -- é usado para atribuir o valor às variáveis **first_tag** e **next_tag**.

Aí entra o `shift` que se encarrega de deslocar os argumentos para a esquerda, assim, o $1 vira $0, o $2 vira $1 etc e o $0 é sempre descartado no processo... isto é feito até que a variável **next_tag** receba um valor vazio, o que significa que não há mais valores e o laço é interrompido.

Comment: Achei apenas estranha a descrição do '$1` virando `$0` e sendo descartado, mas de resto uma ótima resposta

Comment: No Bash o parâmetro $0 é o nome da função/comando que foi invocado, assim a primeira execução recebe algo como "show_commits v3.0 v2.0 v1.0" e eu pego o $1 que é "v3.0"no primeiro **shift** a lista de argumentos vira "v3.0 v2.0 v1.0", quando leio $1 novamente e pego "v2.0" e assim sucessivamente até que a leitura retorne uma _string_ vazia.